# If And Statements in Business Objects/Webi

Tags: object, if-statement, webi

I'm using Web Intelligence in Business Objects 4.2 and I'm trying to create a new variable using the following IF/AND statement but can't seem to get it right:

=If([Safeguarding Ind]=1 And [Form Complete Ind] <> 1 then 1 else 0)

**Error Message**: Missing operator or closing parenthesis in 'Then' at position 54. (IES 10067)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

=[#Encounters] Where ([Safeguarding Form Incomplete] InList (1))